# How to populate a bespoke Django form MultiWidget

Tags: django, django-forms

I have created a bespoke form widget which saves an address as a list.

```
class AddressWidget(MultiWidget):
    def __init__(self, base_widget, attrs=None):
        widgets = (
            forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Address', 'class': 'form-control'}), 
            forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Address Line 2', 'class': 'form-control'}),
            forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'City', 'class': 'form-control'}),
            forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'State', 'class': 'form-control'}),
            forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Postcode', 'class': 'form-control'}),            
        )
        super().__init__(widgets, attrs)

    def decompress(self, value):
        if value:
            return (value.address1, value.address2, value.city, value.state, value.postcode)
        return (None, None, None, None, None)
```

Saving the form works as I want, but when re-entering the form in order to change values, it doesn't get prepopulated, although all other regular fields do.

How do I get it to populate the field?

It is used in the form as:

```
class ResponseForm(forms.ModelForm)
    address = AddressField()
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('address',)
```

```
class AddressField(MultiValueField):
    """
    Custom field to take user inputs of Address
    """
    widget = AddressWidget(base_widget=TextInput)
    
    def __init__(self, *, attrs=None, **kwargs):
        fields = (
            CharField(label=_('Address Line 1'), max_length=25), 
            CharField(label=_('Address Line 2'), max_length=25), 
            CharField(label=_('City'), max_length=25),
            CharField(label=_('State'), max_length=25),
            CharField(label=_('Country'), max_length=25)
        )
        super().__init__(fields, required=False)

    def clean(self, value, initial=None):
        value = super().clean(value)
        return value

    def compress(self, value_list):
        if value_list:
            return value_list
        return [[],[],[]]
```

Within the model it is defined as:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
   address = models.TextField()
   ...
```

A typical value entered might be:

```
123 Some Street
Example Area
This Town
MYP 0ST
```

It is saved to the database table like this in a text field.

**EDIT**

I think my problem is the ResponseForm.  I am using an app and response form is initialising the widgets.

```
class ResponseForm(forms.ModelForm):

    FIELDS = {
        Question.TINY_TEXT: TinyCharField,
        Question.EXTRA_SHORT_TEXT: ExtraShortCharField,
        Question.SHORT_TEXT: ShortCharField,
        Question.TEXT: forms.CharField,
        Question.EXTRA_LONG_TEXT: forms.CharField,
        Question.SELECT_MULTIPLE: forms.MultipleChoiceField,
        Question.INTEGER: forms.IntegerField,
        Question.FLOAT: forms.FloatField,
        Question.DATE: forms.DateField,
        Question.TIME: forms.TimeField,
        Question.CHECK_BOXES: forms.MultipleChoiceField,
        Question.ADDRESS: forms.CharField, #AddressField,
        Question.DISCLAIMER: forms.BooleanField,
        Question.HEIGHT: HeightFormField,
        Question.WEIGHT: WeightFormField,
        Question.RANGE: IntegerRangeField,
        Question.VOLUME: VolumeFormField,
    }    

    WIDGETS = {
        Question.TINY_TEXT: forms.TextInput(),
        Question.EXTRA_SHORT_TEXT: forms.TextInput(),
        Question.SHORT_TEXT: forms.TextInput(),
        Question.TEXT: forms.Textarea(attrs={'maxlength':250}),
        Question.ADDRESS: forms.Textarea(attrs={'maxlength':250}),
        Question.EXTRA_LONG_TEXT: forms.Textarea(attrs={'maxlength':750}),
        Question.RADIO: forms.RadioSelect,
        Question.SELECT: forms.Select,
        Question.SELECT_IMAGE: ImageSelectWidget,
        Question.SELECT_MULTIPLE: forms.SelectMultiple,
        Question.CHECK_BOXES: forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        Question.DATE: DatePickerInput,
        Question.DISCLAIMER: forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'required': True}),                
    }

    class Meta:
        model = Response
        fields = ()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Expects a survey object to be passed in initially"""
        self.survey = kwargs.pop("survey")
        self.user = kwargs.pop("user")
        try:
            self.step = int(kwargs.pop("step"))
        except KeyError:
            self.step = None
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.uuid = uuid.uuid4().hex

        self.categories = self.survey.non_empty_categories()
        self.qs_with_no_cat = self.survey.questions.filter(category__isnull=True).order_by("order", "id")

        if self.survey.display_method == Survey.BY_CATEGORY:
            self.steps_count = len(self.categories) + (1 if self.qs_with_no_cat else 0)
        else:
            self.steps_count = len(self.survey.questions.all())
        # will contain prefetched data to avoid multiple db calls
        self.response = False
        self.answers = False

        self.add_questions(kwargs.get("data"))

        self._get_preexisting_response()

        if not self.survey.editable_answers and self.response is not None:
            for name in self.fields.keys():
                self.fields[name].widget.attrs["disabled"] = True

    def add_questions(self, data):
        '''
        add a field for each survey question, corresponding to the question
        type as appropriate.
        '''

        if self.survey.display_method == Survey.BY_CATEGORY and self.step is not None:
            if self.step == len(self.categories):
                qs_for_step = self.survey.questions.filter(category__isnull=True).order_by("order", "id")
            else:
                qs_for_step = self.survey.questions.filter(category=self.categories[self.step])

            for question in qs_for_step:
                self.add_question(question, data)
        else:
            for i, question in enumerate(self.survey.questions.all()):
                not_to_keep = i != self.step and self.step is not None
                if self.survey.display_method == Survey.BY_QUESTION and not_to_keep:
                    continue
                self.add_question(question, data)

    def current_categories(self):
        if self.survey.display_method == Survey.BY_CATEGORY:
            if self.step is not None and self.step < len(self.categories):
                return [self.categories[self.step]]
            return [Category(name="No category", description="No cat desc")]
        else:
            extras = []
            if self.qs_with_no_cat:
                extras = [Category(name="No category", description="No cat desc")]

            return self.categories + extras

    def _get_preexisting_response(self):
        """Recover a pre-existing response in database.

        The user must be logged. Will store the response retrieved in an attribute
        to avoid multiple db calls.

        :rtype: Response or None"""
        if self.response:
            return self.response

        if not self.user.is_authenticated:
            self.response = None
        else:
            try:
                self.response = Response.objects.prefetch_related("user", "survey").get(
                    user=self.user, survey=self.survey
                )
            except Response.DoesNotExist:
                LOGGER.debug("No saved response for '%s' for user %s", self.survey, self.user)
                self.response = None
        return self.response

    def _get_preexisting_answers(self):
        """Recover pre-existing answers in database.

        The user must be logged. A Response containing the Answer must exists.
        Will create an attribute containing the answers retrieved to avoid multiple
        db calls.

        :rtype: dict of Answer or None"""
        if self.answers:
            return self.answers

        response = self._get_preexisting_response()
        if response is None:
            self.answers = None
        try:
            answers = Answer.objects.filter(response=response).prefetch_related("question")
            self.answers = {answer.question.id: answer for answer in answers.all()}
        except Answer.DoesNotExist:
            self.answers = None

        return self.answers

    def _get_preexisting_answer(self, question):
        """Recover a pre-existing answer in database.

        The user must be logged. A Response containing the Answer must exists.

        :param Question question: The question we want to recover in the
        response.
        :rtype: Answer or None"""
        answers = self._get_preexisting_answers()
        return answers.get(question.id, None)

    def get_question_initial(self, question, data):
        """Get the initial value that we should use in the Form

        :param Question question: The question
        :param dict data: Value from a POST request.
        :rtype: String or None"""
        initial = None
        answer = self._get_preexisting_answer(question)
        if answer:
            # Initialize the field with values from the database if any
            if question.type in [Question.SELECT_MULTIPLE]:
                initial = []
                if answer.body == "[]":
                    pass
                elif "[" in answer.body and "]" in answer.body:
                    initial = []
                    unformated_choices = answer.body[1:-1].strip()
                    for unformated_choice in unformated_choices.split(settings.CHOICES_SEPARATOR):
                        choice = unformated_choice.split("'")[1]
                        initial.append(slugify(choice))
                else:
                    # Only one element
                    initial.append(slugify(answer.body))

            elif question.type == Question.DATE:
                initial = datetime.datetime.strptime(answer.body, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
            else:
                initial = answer.body
        if data:
            # Initialize the field field from a POST request, if any.
            # Replace values from the database
            initial = data.get("question_%d" % question.pk)
        return initial

    def get_question_widget(self, question):
        """Return the widget we should use for a question.

        :param Question question: The question
        :rtype: django.forms.widget or None"""
        try:
            return self.WIDGETS[question.type]
        except KeyError:
            return None

    @staticmethod
    def get_question_choices(question):
        """Return the choices we should use for a question.

        :param Question question: The question
        :rtype: List of String or None"""
        qchoices = None
        if question.type not in [Question.TEXT, Question.SHORT_TEXT, Question.INTEGER, Question.FLOAT, Question.DATE]:
            qchoices = question.get_choices()
            # add an empty option at the top so that the user has to explicitly
            # select one of the options
            if question.type in [Question.SELECT, Question.SELECT_IMAGE]:
                qchoices = tuple([("", "-------------")]) + qchoices
        return qchoices

    def get_question_field(self, question, **kwargs):
        """Return the field we should use in our form.

        :param Question question: The question
        :param **kwargs: A dict of parameter properly initialized in
            add_question.
        :rtype: django.forms.fields"""
        # logging.debug("Args passed to field %s", kwargs)
        try:
            return self.FIELDS[question.type](**kwargs)
        except KeyError:
            return forms.ChoiceField(**kwargs)

    def add_question(self, question, data):
        """Add a question to the form.

        :param Question question: The question to add.
        :param dict data: The pre-existing values from a post request."""
        kwargs = {"label": question.text, "required": question.required}
        initial = self.get_question_initial(question, data)
        if initial:
            kwargs["initial"] = initial
        choices = self.get_question_choices(question)
        if choices:
            kwargs["choices"] = choices
        widget = self.get_question_widget(question)
        if widget:
            kwargs["widget"] = widget
        field = self.get_question_field(question, **kwargs)
        field.widget.attrs["category"] = question.category.name if question.category else ""

        if question.type == Question.DATE:
            field.widget.attrs["class"] = "date"
        # logging.debug("Field for %s : %s", question, field.__dict__)
        self.fields["question_%d" % question.pk] = field

    def has_next_step(self):
        if not self.survey.is_all_in_one_page():
            if self.step < self.steps_count - 1:
                return True
        return False

    def next_step_url(self):
        if self.has_next_step():
            context = {"id": self.survey.id, "step": self.step + 1}
            return reverse("survey:survey-detail-step", kwargs=context)

    def current_step_url(self):
        return reverse("survey-detail-step", kwargs={"id": self.survey.id, "step": self.step})

    def save(self, commit=True):
        """Save the response object"""
        # Recover an existing response from the database if any
        #  There is only one response by logged user.
        response = self._get_preexisting_response()
        if not self.survey.editable_answers and response is not None:
            return None
        if response is None:
            response = super().save(commit=False)
        response.survey = self.survey
        response.interview_uuid = self.uuid
        if self.user.is_authenticated:
            response.user = self.user
        response.save()
        # response "raw" data as dict (for signal)
        data = {"survey_id": response.survey.id, "interview_uuid": response.interview_uuid, "responses": []}
        # create an answer object for each question and associate it with this
        # response.
        for field_name, field_value in list(self.cleaned_data.items()):
            if field_name.startswith("question_"):
                # warning: this way of extracting the id is very fragile and
                # entirely dependent on the way the question_id is encoded in
                # the field name in the __init__ method of this form class.
                q_id = int(field_name.split("_")[1])
                question = Question.objects.get(pk=q_id)
                answer = self._get_preexisting_answer(question)
                if answer is None:
                    answer = Answer(question=question)
                if question.type == Question.SELECT_IMAGE:
                    value, img_src = field_value.split(":", 1)
                    # TODO Handling of SELECT IMAGE
                    LOGGER.debug("Question.SELECT_IMAGE not implemented, please use : %s and %s", value, img_src)
                answer.body = field_value
                data["responses"].append((answer.question.id, answer.body))
                LOGGER.debug("Creating answer for question %d of type %s : %s", q_id, answer.question.type, field_value)
                answer.response = response
                answer.save()
        survey_completed.send(sender=Response, instance=response, data=data)
        return response
```

Comment: Why is ResponseForm completely different now? How are you using it?

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `address` is stored as `models.TextField()` and retrieved as  Python `str` in the model:

1. In `MultiWidget` `decompress`, load from `str`:

```py
class AddressWidget(MultiWidget):
    ...

    def decompress(self, value):
        if value:
            return json.loads(value)
        return (None, None, None, None, None)
```

2. In `MultiValueField` `compress`, dump to `str`:

```py
class AddressField(MultiValueField):
    ...

    def compress(self, value_list):
        if value_list:
            return json.dumps(value_list)
        return ''
```

Comment: I'm awarding the bounty here because this would work if I wasn't messing about with my form so much.  I need to work out how to simplify it

Comment: @HenryM I'm still very much interested to work on your problem if you are able to create a repro project on GitHub.